# How to retrieve the data of my matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Using numpy for the first time, so I am not familiar with it, I am having a `matrix()` object and if I print it to screen I see the following:

```
[[{('C', 'V'): 0.0000001, ('T', 'L'): 0.00002, etc.}]]
```

How do I get this:

```
{('C', 'V'): 0.0000001, ('T', 'L'): 0.00002, etc.}
```

out of the matrix?
Is there just some sort of index for it?

Comment: It is good idea to spent at least 5 minutes reading the basics about the tool you are using before asking such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for `numpy.matrix` are [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). A quick scan over it should give you this, for a single-element matrix:

```
In [9]: b = np.matrix({"key": "value", ("A", "B"): (1,2,3)})

In [10]: b.item()
Out[10]: {('A', 'B'): (1, 2, 3), 'key': 'value'}
```

For a multi-element matrix, pass the index of the object you want to `item()`.

Comment: Thank you, for answering my question politely. Even though it is a simple question.